# PHP - Execute some code on every error or warning

Tags: php, error-handling

I am looking for a **generic way** to execute some code on every error / warning etc.

I have multiple websites with the same code base and I would like to collect all the errors in one centralized place. For this I need a callback that is invoked every time an error is thrown.

Is it possible to achieve this using PHP only (code or configuration) or I need to go down to web-server level?

Comment: [`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/function.set-error-handler.php)

Comment: The following error types cannot be handled with a user defined function in `set_error_handler()`: E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT raised in the file where set_error_handler() is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, no. If PHP crashes (and thus generates an error) there is no easy way to collect that error, because the script that was called will stop after it encounters the error.

[`set_error_handler()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) goes some way to solve this, but many error types (E_ERROR, E_PARSE, E_CORE_ERROR, E_CORE_WARNING, E_COMPILE_ERROR, E_COMPILE_WARNING, and most of E_STRICT) will not be caught this way.

If the errors are created by classes and methods that produce exceptions, catch as many as you can using [`try{} catch{}`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) structures.

You could conceivably set up your environment that every PHP call is actually a call to a master-PHP file that then executes PHP scripts and collects the output and displays that to the user, but that a lot of unnecessary complexity.

If you're running an [AJAX environment](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) (where PHP calls are via AJAX calls, not changes in the URL), you could set up a JavaScript listener that catches unexpected results and stores them. That's the way I currently do it.

I would love to hear from others if there are any other tricks to catching errors.